# How to watch the death of a remote actor in Akka cluster?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I'm using Akka sharding cluster to distribute my workload across multiple nodes, and use `context.watchWith(worker)` to detect the unexpected termination of a child actor.

It seems if the child actor is allocated on a different node from the parent node (by cluster sharding), and if that child node is down, the parent actor will not get the death notification of the child actor.

I know I can add my own logic to track the lifecycle of the child actor.
Still, I'm wondering, does Akka have native support of the death watch for this case (child actor on a remote node)?

Answer (score 1):

That is not true in general, watching an `ActorRef` that lives on another node will give you a terminated message if that actor stops.

However, when using Cluster Sharding you don't actually have access to the remote `ActorRef` but use sharding as a proxy to deliver your messages based on a field in the message. Sharding can decide to rebalance the shards across the cluster at any time, for example when a new node joins or a node leaves the cluster and in that case the sharded actors can be stopped and upon the next message be started on another node.

If the motivation for watching the remote actor is to get some form of delivery guarantee it could be interesting to know that we added a new tool called [Reliable Delivery](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/reliable-delivery.html#reliable-delivery) in Akka 2.6.4 that was recently released. You can see it used in a distributed workload sample in this PR https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/pull/186

Comment: Thanks! My question is not quite valid. There's no parent-child relationship when the worker actor is created by cluster sharding. So to know if the worker actor (created by cluster sharding) is alive or not, the solutions include worker actor sends its `ActorRef` back for death watch, or use heartbeat to ping the worker actor for aliveness checking. Am I right?

Comment: That would be one way to do it but it could be better to take a step back and think about if watching the child from the requestee is the right way to achieve that.